# How to save to server dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript

In laravel 5.7 / jquery 3 app looking at the snippet https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ykXa

I made similar, but having several input/select elements.
I add new row with input/select elements code :

```
         $(document).on('click', '.todo-btn-add', function(e)
         {
             e.preventDefault();
             var todos_count= parseInt($("#todos_count").val())+1

             var controlForm = $('.controls form:first'),
                 currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first'),
                 newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);


             var modifiedHidden= newEntry.find('input');
             modifiedHidden.val('1');
             modifiedHidden.attr('id','todo_modified_'+todos_count);     
             modifiedHidden.attr('name','todo_modified_'+todos_count);

             var todo_text_input= modifiedHidden.next( "input" )
             todo_text_input.val('');
             todo_text_input.attr('id','todo_text_'+todos_count);
             todo_text_input.attr('name','todo_text_'+todos_count);      

             var todo_select_priority= newEntry.find( "select" )
             todo_select_priority.val('');
             todo_select_priority.attr('id','todo_priority_'+todos_count);
             todo_select_priority.attr('name','todo_priority_'+todos_count);

             var todo_select_completed= todo_select_priority.find( "select" )
             todo_select_completed.val('');
             todo_select_completed.attr('id','todo_completed_'+todos_count);
             todo_select_completed.attr('name','todo_completed_'+todos_count);


             controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .todo-btn-add')
                 .removeClass('todo-btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
                 .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                 .html('<span class="fa fa-minus"></span>');

             $("#todos_count").val(  todos_count  )
         }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e)
         {
             $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();
             $("#todos_count").val(  parseInt($("#todos_count").val())-1  )
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
         });
```

But problem that saving the form I collect all data in 1 array to save it on server with:

> ```
>  function saveTodoDialog( csrf_token ) {
>      let todos_count= $("#todos_count").val()
>      let todosList= [];
>      for(let i= 0; i< todos_count; i++) {
>          let todoItem = {
>              todo_id: $("#todo_id_" + i).val(),
>              todo_modified: $("#todo_modified_" + i).val(),
>              todo_text: $("#todo_text_" + i).val(),
>              todo_priority: $("#todo_priority_" + i).val(),
>              todo_completed: $("#todo_completed_" + i).val()
>          }; //Object initialiser
>          alert("todos_count::"+todos_count+ "  i::"+i+"todoItem::"+var_dump(todoItem) )
>          todosList.push(todoItem);
>      }
>
>  console.log("todosList::")
>  console.log( todosList )
>
>  let href =  "/admin/save-todo-page";
>  $.ajax({
>      type: "POST",
>      dataType: "json",
>      url: href,
>      data: { "_token": csrf_token, "todosList" : todosList },
>      success: function (response) {
>          popupAlert("Todo items were saved successfully !", 'success')
>      },
>      error: function (error) {
>          popupErrorMessage(error.responseJSON.message)
>      }
>  });
> ```

But checking data for any row I see that all data for newly added rows has undefined value.
How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any code related to making a request to the server. Maybe show us that code?

Comment: I added the request to server code, but the thing is in content of todosList array : for dynamically added rows ALL VALUES ARE INDEFINED - I see it alert

Comment: Maybe /admin/save-todo-page is not handling your ajax as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error is happening because you are getting undefined from your inputs, I suggest adjusting your `saveTodoDialog()` method.

```
function saveTodoDialog( csrf_token ) {
     let todoList = Array.prototype.slice
     .call( document.querySelectorAll('input.form-control') )
     .map( (todo, index) => {
        // Create Individual TODO object
     });

    // Make server request

}
```